# Make last item in a list fill the rest of the container

Tags: css, responsive-design, background-color

I have an inline list with elements of unknown width, and I want the last item to have a different background color than the rest, and take up all the remaining space to the right.

I'm working with a given HTML and I can't modify it, so I'm looking for a way to use solely CSS (I don't think I can use JS either). I made a [simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbFZ6/) to show what I need, the background of the last item should go all the way to the end of the browser window (to the right).

As an example, my HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li class="last">item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and for the CSS, I tried:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 70%, red 30%);
```

on the div, but since the site has to be responsive, the percentages don't really work like I need, they either don't cover enough or overlap over the preceding item as the screen size changes.

Is there another CSS-way to do this?

Comment: So in this example, you want the first 3 items to be left justified and the last item to fill up the width of the line?

Comment: Yes, the menu should be centered and the last item's background should go all the way to the right of the screen.

Comment: What determines the overall width of `ul`?

Comment: The width is unknown, it depends on the menu items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it using a combination of CSS tables, a pseudo element and absolute positioning.

For the following **HTML**:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li class="last">item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

apply the following **CSS**:

```
div {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div ul {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
div ul li {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
div ul li.last {
}
div ul li.last:before {
    content: '\a0'; /* \a0 is hex code for a non-breaking space */
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

To get a shink-to-fit width for the list items, apply `display: table` to the `ul` element, which you can center using using `margin: 0 auto` since tables are block level elements.

Apply `display: table-cell` to the `li` elements and optionally, apply some padding.

To get the red background, apply a `:before` pseudo-element to `li.last` and position it absolutely by setting `top: 0` and use `height: 100%` to match the height from the `div` wrapping block (which is has `position: relative` to set the frame of reference for the absolute positioning.

The width of 100% on the pseudo-element will cause an overflow condition, but you can take care of that by using `overflow: hidden` on the `div`.

If you apply horizontal padding to the `li`, you will need to compensate with a negative left margin to get the background color to line up with the edge of the table-cell block.

Finally to get the background pseudo-element to stack behind the text, set `z-index: -1`,
or some suitable value depending on what other components are on your page.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/EruT7/

In Firefox, the results look like:

[image]

Comment: Amazing! I would've never thought of using a pseudo-element like this, it worked like a charm. Thank you :)

Comment: Initially, I didn't think this was possible, glad to help!  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

check this out

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

this css selector are pretty useful on this cases

so you can say something like:

```
div ul li:last-child{
    /*things for extend the tag area*/
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #555;
}
```

and if u want more, check the whole reference

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Gl : )

Comment: This selector alone targets the last item, but it doesn't help to extend the color beyond the li's width.

Comment: with the padding your can add area to the background, and remember you can set padding for each side by: padding:5px 6px 7px 8px;  and it would be for top, right, bottom, and left.

Comment: The thing is I need the color to extend to the end of the screen, which is an unknown variable since the site is responsive. The padding won't help since I don't have a fixed dimension to work with :(

Answer (score 0):

with your current css (inline element with centered text), it's impossible to make it works correctly. below example will works in different way than the example you provide.

```
div ul {list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
div ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    background: white
}
div ul li:last-child {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    background-color: red
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blackbiron/X4tTw/